# node.exe does not read file, but returns ellipsis (...)

Tags: node.js

End feb 2014 I downloaded node to c:\dev\0.10\ of my windows 7 machine, and node.exe opens fine. 
Inspired by Smashing Node (some book), I want to achieve the following:

Firefox shows the plain text Smashing Node! if i point it to localhost:3000 and run in the node console

```
node my-web-server.js
```

where my-web-server.js file next to node.exe contains

```
require('http').createServer(function(req,res){res.writeHead(200, ('Content-Type', 'text/html'));res.end('<marquee>Smashing Node!</marquee>');}).listen(3000);;
```

but I fail: browser says

```
cannot connect with webserver on localhost:3000.
```

If paste the above oneliner in node it reacts with

```
{ domain: null,
  _events: ..etc...  }
```

Ignoring that, browser F5 results in Smashing Node!.

Node refuses the simplest of files, say have a file called hello.js next to node.exe and file contains the ascii text 
    console.log("hello");
i type:

```
node hello.js
```

node returns

```
...
```

(an ellipsis in dark gray)
Expected was: node returns hello

i type a file that does not exist like this:

```
node die
```

node returns

```
...
```

if i type

```
var http = require('http');
```

node:

```
undefined
```

(in a darkish gray) Expected was: something like ok, especially since the above oneliner resulted in a web server.

If however i type

```
npm install colors
```

node reacts with

```
npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell. (Press Control-D to exit.)
```

of course

```
node --version
```

also responds with an ellipsis.

What can i do?
How do i make node to process files?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `node hello.js` (and `npm`) on your command line shell (e.g. `cmd.com` or Windows PowerShell).

You are trying to run it in the Node REPL (node console), where you are expected to type only JavaScript.

Comment: aha. So when working on node do NOT use the node shell, but you run commands via the command shell?

Comment: No. Just the one to run your script. There's no need to run the REPL unless you want to write JS line by line (which can be useful for testing stuff).

Comment: you're right. Even better than right: i seem to have node on my PATH and can just run it from anywhere. Thanks! You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where the Smashing Node failed, particularly as a one-liner. The code runs OK on my machine, but you can split the code as follow and add a few console.log() to see how is executing:

```
console.log('about to start listening for requests');
require('http').createServer( function(req,res) { 
    console.log('a request was received', req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, ('Content-Type', 'text/html'));
    res.end('<marquee>Smashing Node!</marquee>');
}).listen(3000);;
console.log('listening for requests');
```

Save this code as my-web-server.js as you did before and then run from the command line "node my-web-server.js" and point your browser to localhost:3000

Also, I've got a very basic Node.js tutorial that might help you with the basics: http://hectorcorrea.com/#/blog/introduction-to-node-js/51

Comment: I took care to point out that node hello.js gives '...' Your tutorial also fails to mention that node must be run from commmand prompt INSTEAD of node repl. Oh well perhaps I am the only noob in the world that made that mistake.